# Android: Icons remain in status bar after app is swiped-out on Recents window

Tags: android

On Android 13 / 14 on Android Studio. The problem appears on a Pixel 4a phone, too.

When the app has placed a notification icon on the status bar, the icon is easily removed it on exit from the app by a cleanup method. However, when the app is swiped up on the Recents window the icon remains, indicating that the normal exit from the app has not been taken. (The app has exited, however.)

How can I programatically assure the swiping-up on the Recents page will allow my execution of the cleanup function?

I've tried setting Activity attributes to not show the app in the Recents window. This restricts to app's appearance to one time in the Recents window.  However, even this one time, swiping-up leaves the icon hanging.

I'm NOT running any Service.

Comment: Adding a clear() function in the Activity's onDestroy() clause helps a lot. By itself, however, it's clearing is unreliable on both Android 13 and 14 emulators on Android Studio.